# Optimal path with multiple costs

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, oc.optimization-and-control

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, each edge $e$ has $k$ costs $c_i(e)$, $1\le i\le k$. Correspondingly, a path $P$ is also characterized by $k$ costs where $c_i(P)=\sum_{e\in P} c_i(e)$. Given vertices $s$ and $t$, we seek a path between them that minimizes the maximal cost. Mathematically, we seek

$$P^*=\min_{P\in{\cal P}_{st}} \max_{1\le i\le k} c_i(P)$$

My question is: Is this problem related to some known NP-hard problem? How to prove the hardness?

Comment: What are restrictions on $P$? Is a $P$ with no edges allowed? Also the formula for $P^*$ seems to have a $\min$ instead of $\max$.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov Thank you for pointing out the typo. I don't catch your question. $P$ is a path composed of edges, no other particular constraint.

Comment: Can $c_i(e)$ be negative? Does $P$ have to be vertex- or edge-simple?

Comment: Consider the baseline case that $c_i(e)$ are positive and $P$ is vertex- and edge-simple.

Comment: If $c_i(e)$ are positive, then clearly a single-edge $P$ is optimal.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to specify the source and destination.

Answer (score 0):

When $k \geq 2$ we can reduce from the NP-hard [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). For a given multiset $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}$ with even sum $X = \sum_{i = 1}^n s_i$ create $n + 1$ vertices $s = v_0, \ldots, v_n = t$, and for each $i = 0, \ldots, n - 1$ connect vertices $v_i$ and $v_{i + 1}$ by two paths of costs, say, $(2, 2 + s_i)$ and $(2 + s_i, 2)$ (to avoid multiple edges). Then a partition of $S$ exists iff $P^* = 2n + X / 2$.

Comment: Thank you. Nice proof.Could you pls have a look at another problem I posed some days ago: I think the problem is NP-complete but fail to prove it. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373109/minimum-delay-path-in-time-dependent-graph

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the NP-hardness, but you can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $(i,j)\in E$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ represent the flow from $i$ to $j$.  The problem is to minimize $z$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j)\in E} x_{i,j} - \sum_{(j,i)\in E} x_{j,i} &= 
\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if $i=s$}\\ -1 &\text{if $i=t$}\\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases} && \text{for $i\in V$}\\
x_{i,j} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $(i,j)\in E$}\\
z &\ge \sum_{(i,j)\in E} c_{i,j}^r x_{i,j} &&\text{for $r\in\{1,\dots,k\}$}
\end{align}